# How to scan a slow InputStream with minimal delay?

Tags: inputstream, java.util.scanner, java-io

Here is a mock `InputStream` that simulates a slow stream:

```
class SlowInputStream extends InputStream{
    private String internal = "5 6\nNext Line\n";
    private int position = 0;

    @Override
    public int available(){
        if(position==internal.length()) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IOException("Sleep Interrupted");
        }
        if(position==internal.length()) return -1;
        return internal.charAt(position++);

    }

}
```

And here is the test code:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new SlowInputStream());

    int i=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("i="+i);
    int j=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("j="+j);
    s.nextLine();
    String line = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("line="+line);

    s.close();
```

The behavior of the above code is it stops for a while and prints three lines. What code can output the same thing but split the waiting time between the lines?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override read(byte[], int, int) as well. You'd be better off extending FilterInoutStream: that's what it's for.

Comment: Overriding `read` is not enough. `Scanner` will keep calling it until it receives 4096 bytes or reaches the end of the stream in my machine. The same apply to `FilterInoutStream`.

Answer (score -1):

If a `Scanner` is created from `InputStream`, it will try to read a specific amount of data each time, to improve performance. In my machine, the amount is 4096 bytes. This is why in this example it always keep waiting until prints all result at the same time.

To bypass this cache mechanism interface `Readable` should be used rather than a raw stream. Because there are no known implementations can do so, one have to implement their own. (If somebody know such a thing please let me know) So the following code can do the job:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new Readable(){

    private InputStream is = new SlowInputStream();

    public int read(CharBuffer arg0) throws IOException {
        int i = is.read();
        if(i>=0){
            arg0.append((char)i);
            return 1;
        } else return -1;
    }

});

int i=s.nextInt();
System.out.println("i="+i);
int j=s.nextInt();
System.out.println("j="+j);
s.nextLine();
String line = s.nextLine();
System.out.println("line="+line);

s.close();
```

EDIT: the above solution has some disadvantage. First it does not close the internal input stream so there is a leak. Second, it depends on the charset is single byte. It will not work for multiple byte charsets (i.e. UTF-8). To solve these issue we can use a `ReadableByteChannel` instead:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new ReadableByteChannel(){

    private InputStream is = new SlowInputStream();
    boolean isopen = true;

    public int read(ByteBuffer arg0) throws IOException {
        int i = is.read();
        if(i>=0){
            arg0.put((byte)i);
            return 1;
        } else return -1;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        isopen=false;
        is.close();
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        return isopen;
    }

});
```

EDIT: Thanks for the comment, I have fixed an error in text and given better explanation of this issue.

Comment: What 'default cache of an InputStream' are you talking about exactly? Why does Readable solve this imaginary problem?

Comment: I think that is a mistake. The cache is actually used by `Scanner`. If the scanner were created from an `InputStream`, it will try to read a specific amount (4096 bytes in my case) of data each time. So in this example it will keep reading until all data has been received. By using `Readable` or `ReadableByteChannel`, `Scanner` will only read bytes whenever required to do so.